# Why isn’t ObjectDataSource’s matching algorithm as flexible as…?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, objectdatasource, sqldatasource

Even though *UpdateNames* stored procedure only takes one parameter named *@First*, we are still able to define additional parameter named *Last*, and the update will still be successful:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ... UpdateCommand="UpdateNames"
        UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="First" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Last" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

But when dealing with ObjectDataSource control, the number of parameters defined in ObjectDataSource must exactly match the number of parameters defined in *UpdateNames()* method. Thus, if *UpdateNames()* takes only one parameter named *First*, the following will cause an exception

```
     <asp:ObjectDataSource ... UpdateMethod="UpdateNames">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="First" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Last" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

A) Why isn’t ObjectDataSource’s matching algorithm as flexible as SqlDataSource’s matching algorithm and thus ignores any extra parameters?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The ObjectDataSource trades one kind of flexibility for another.

You are correct that your function's parameters much match the listed parameters exactly, but it is for a good reason.

The ObjectDataSource lets you define multiple functions to handle different parameters, so if you want to support a UpdateNames() method that can take either a first name or a first and last name, you just define both functions and handle them however you see fit.

```
using System.ComponentModel;

[DataObject]
public class MyODS
{
    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Update)]
    public void UpdateNames(string First)
    {
        UpdateNames(First, null)
    }

    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Update)]
    public void UpdateNames(string First, string Last)
    {
        //Do the update
    }
}
```

Comment: So if ObjectDataSource had the same matching algorithm as SqlDataSource, then it might not know which of the overloaded methods to call?!

Answer (score 1):

A complete guess, from experience with the two:

The SQL version will just go through the array an SQL script to excute the stored procedure, Appending the variables as it goes.

The ObjectDataSource uses reflection to find a update method that matches the parameters passed. So it fails if no matching method exists on the object that takes the supplied parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of it as if your SqlDataSource were "translated" into sql, and this is perfectly valid sql:

```
DECLARE @First varchar(50)
DECLARE @Last varchar(50)
SELECT @First = 'some value', @Last = 'some other value'

SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WHERE FirstName= @First
```

On the other hand, you can think of an ObjectDataSource as if it were translated into calls using Reflection functions like `PropertyInfo.GetValue()` and `PropertyInfo.SetValue()`.  If you call one of those using an object or field that doesn't exist, you'll get an exception.